# CSS Simple Photo Gallery Question

Tags: css

This is my first question on Stack Overflow.  I heard this site was a great resource for website developers.  I'm new and still learning so this should be easy.

I am making a photo gallery that has a few small thumbnail images and a large image in the middle, all on the same page.  I want to make it so that when you click on each thumbnail the large image in the middle of the page changes.

Is there a way to do this with pure CSS and no javascript?  Is it also possible to preload all the large images so that each time you click a thumbnail the large image in the middle just pops right up?

Thank you in advance for any help!  I look forward to participating here often!

Comment: It's certainly possible to do it without javascript using the `:active` selector, but it's not recommended.

And yes, you can preload the images with hidden `<img />` tags, but it's not recommended as it loads images that the user might not look at (and therefore wastes bandwidth).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this with pure CSS and no javascript?

It is possible, but not well supported in browsers.

You could link to the images and use [:target](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo) to change the [display property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop) from none to block.

The problem with this is that if the browser supports `display` (i.e. almost all of them) but not `:target` (i.e. lots of them) then some images will simply be unavailable.

> Is it also possible to preload all the large images so that each time you click a thumbnail the large image in the middle just pops right up?

This would achieve that.

However, preloading the large versions of all the images would be quite a painful load on users' bandwidth.

Individual pages which use some form of include or server side process to duplicate the navigation are still the way to go.

Comment: The "large" images actually still have very small file sizes and there are only 7 of them.  Preloading should still only take seconds so I think it will be ok.  But I will test it out to make sure.  Thanx for the tip!

Comment: +1 for `:target`. It would be great to see those out in the wild more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a good way to do this with *no* Javascript.

With minimal Javascript, you could have all of the large images hidden, and use `onClick` on the thumbnails to un-hide the appropriate image.

With more Javascript, you could keep changing the `src` attribute of the large image and preload images using Javascript as well (see http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jpreload.htm).

Comment: Thank you for the link to pageresource.  Your link looks like it should help me with preloading the large images.  It also led me to this link.

http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jhover1.htm

This one helped me out a lot.  They describe how to change an image on the page by clicking a link.  This should be the trick for allowing me to click a thumbnail on the page and have the large image change.  I will let you all know if it works.  I should be able to code it up later tonight or tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

A [google search](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=pure+css+gallery&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=CY1UI7jk2TKTJDYfAzQTWkKT_CwAAAKoEBU_QYIVZ&fp=37132dca8f7438ee) brought back some methods using pure CSS but I would suggest using a jquery plug-in like [galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/).  JQuery Plugins make this easy.

Comment: Galleria looks nice.  I still might try coding something simple first but I will keep that in mind.